# What happens when app have access to your photos?

Tags: ios, iphone, permissions, whatsapp, image

These days I see many apps request access to photos on iPhone. I understand app request access to photos to iOS which then request access to me, that sounds ok. In that context  I can allow access to all photos or just some (I don't remember all the options).

What happens when app have access to your photos? Does it mean the app can use the photos for whatever?

I guess an app will not publish my photos somewhere else but perhaps it will consume all the information it can get from that photos.

If I give access to all photos (i.e. to whatsapp), because I don't want't to bother about this again, it means the app will have unrestricted access to the photos.

Let's say I write down a password in a piece of paper and take a photo, it sounds to me an app with access to my photos can get that quite easily.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, yes, the app could do whatever it wants with the files. You may need to check the terms and conditions for whatever app to see what usage you have explicitly agreed to.

In general, you have to trust the app and its vendor to not abuse their access or become compromised. This is true for installing any software on any system.

Comment: This is correct, with the added caveats that mobile apps are usually restricted from running in the background much (which means e.g. taking a picture and then deleting it makes any given app less likely to "see" it), and also mobile apps are supposedly screened for malicious behavior by the app store. In practice such screening is full of holes and ways to slip past at least for a little while, so you definitely shouldn't assume that something from the app store is definitely safe, but it is slightly likelier to be safe than random desktop software from a source that doesn't care at all.